# how to check an object is null in XHTML?

Tags: ajax, xhtml, null

how to check an object (inputtext) is null in XHTML

if have this
rendered="#{movimientoManualBean.bandejaTarea.runPersona != null}"
but is always hide my datatable

only is for hide a datetable before if  i have any records the list what i want show

Comment: what language do you use? XSLT? where do you put this rendered=...?

Comment: Please elaborate; maybe provide some code. It is really difficult to understand what you are asking. For example, is `rendered` a variable? How are you using AJAX?

Comment: Also, your question has nothing to do with XHTML. Nor, as far as I can tell, with AJAX. Then there's the inputtext you mention, which in Javascript is a) retrieved with `element.value` rather than `element.runPersona`, and b) never null, just `""` if it's empty, or `undefined` if you're unlucky. So you don't really mean an input text, do you? And what is the datatable you want to hide? Is it a generated table with data, that you mean to be invisible when there is no data to show?